# how big can be the string sent back to the server with the following code?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, postback

Hello i need to send some data back to the server and i want to use the following code.

Does someone know if there is a limit on the dimension of the string sent with the following code

This is my js code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test.aspx/PassBackdata",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              data: "{'args': '" + Ldata + "'}",
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: AjaxSucceeded,
                   error: AjaxFailed
               });
           });


      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using POST the data you are sending to the server could be arbitrarily large and is controlled by the [`<httRuntime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) element in your web.config:

```
<!-- Limit the request size to 4MB -->    
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="4096" />
```

and if you host in IIS7+ you should also use the [`<requestLimits>`](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits) tag:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <!-- Limit the request size to 4MB -->    
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4194304" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Also I would recommend you using the `JSON.stringify` method to ensure that the data is properly encoded:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.aspx/PassBackdata",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ args: Ldata }),
    dataType: "json",
    success: AjaxSucceeded,
    error: AjaxFailed
});
```

Comment: Or by the respective configuration of whatever public-facing web server proxies your requests to ASP.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the server settings - what amount of data it would accept and how long it would wait for the data. Usually the default setting is for few MB (8 MB in PHP, not sure for ASP.NET) but it depends on the config. Howerver, large data will affect user experience and the page may be noticebly slow far before reaching the web server limits.

Answer (score 1):

The web server usually have a limit for how large a request can be. It varies from one server type to another, and is also configurable.

The default limit for Windows IIS, for example, is 4 MB.